# Show email from the time of sent in view online

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an email for which the looukup data extension will be continually updated and I need to show the users the email at the time of sent when they click on the view online.

E.g. John buys Wednesday, Thursday and Friday on our website and he receives a confirmation order after each purchase. All these orders go in the same data extension. I need him to be able to see the confirmation email with the info from Wednesday when he opens the Wednesday email in view online anytime he opens the email even after he ordered more products. Same with Thursday and Friday.

In the subscribers list and the lookup file we have the subscriber ID and order ID. In the lookup file we have an unique tracking number for each product he buys.

How can I use these to have the view online email to show the emails at the time of sent?

I cannot use this [**Display Send Time Content Contextually**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_examples/display_send_time_content_contextually/) because the account is not enabled with the send logging feature.